# Кнопка никак не реагирует на нажатие

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-intent

есть фрагмент:

```
 public class maindd2 extends Fragment  {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maindd2, container, false);

            Button button2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.butt2);
            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(maindd2.this.getActivity(), actDD1.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            return v;

        }

    }
```

вот эта кнопка, которая прописана в режиме теста, вообще никак нее раегирует на нажатие, ни ошибки ни чего.
    далее разметка страницы

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mainbg"
    tools:context=".maindd2">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Porkal"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/butt2" />

</FrameLayout>
```

[image: так же манифест]

Если кому не трудно объясните для чайника прям по самому простому

```
public class MainDD extends AppCompatActivity {


    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_dd);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }


        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            View rootView = null;
            switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER))
            {
                case 1:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dd, container, false);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maindd2, container, false);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maindd3, container, false);
                    break;
            }
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Короче я отредактировал твой класс и это, не запихай все в один класс хорошо.

вот  MainDD activity:

```
public class MainDD extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mFragmentAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_dd);

    mFragmentAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
    mFragmentAdapter.addFragment(new PlaceholderFragment());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mFragmentAdapter);
}
```

}

и потом создай новый адаптер

такой:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
   super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
   return mFragmentList.size();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment){
   mFragmentList.add(fragment);
}
```

}

после этого создай новый fragment и все если возникнут проблемы пиши.

Comment: СПАСИБО!!! заработало

Comment: рад за тебя!!!!

Answer (score 3):

По моему у вас все должно работать, но попробуйте так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), actDD1.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Если это тоже не поможет, то тогда проверти свой *button*, реагирует ли оно на нажатия.
Можете проверит с помощью Toast или LOG, ну как вам угодно.

Comment: Пробовал так не работает,

Comment: МБ надо еще что-то прописать в главном активити фрагмента?

Comment: Кнопка вообще реагирует на нажатия?

Comment: ну сама кнопка да, на экаране маленько меняется когда нажимаю

Comment: Ну не знаю, нужно посмотреть на код главного _activity_ и  код этого _activity_ actDD1.class

Comment: Код actDD1.class пустой, там ничего нет кроме стандартной шапки, а код  MainDD, сейчас покажу, пожалуйста помоги разобраться, неделю уже маюсь

Comment: хорошо давай...

Comment: две картинки добавил

Comment: @SergeyGudzenko, не надо картинки - лучше текстом.

Comment: @woesss Добавил